# Create nested Subentities in Forms

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig, symfony6

My Entity Tree looks like this:

> ```
> basicpage
> |_ contentModule  (parent)
>     |_ textModule  (child)
>     |_ mediaModule (child)
>          |_ mediaElement
> ```

I have a Basic Page Entity which has a collection of content modules. Now I want to create multiple childrens of contentModules within the basicpage form. To manage these childrens I try to use doctrine and [inheritence mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). I try the following:

### Basicpage Entity

```
 class Basicpage 
 {
 #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'basicpage', targetEntity: ContentModule::class, cascade:["persist"])]
 private $contentModules;
```

### ContentModule (parent entity)

```
 #[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ContentModuleRepository::class)]
 #[ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")]
 #[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: "disc", type: "string")]
 #[ORM\DiscriminatorMap(["textModule" => TextModule::class,"mediaModule" => MediaModule::class])]

 class ContentModule
 {
 #[ORM\Id]
 #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
 #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
 protected $id;

 #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Basicpage::class, inversedBy: 'contentModules')]
 private $basicpage;
```

### TextModule (child entity)

```
class TextModule extends ContentModule 
{

private $type = 'textModule';

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 6000)]
private $text;
```

### MediaModule (child entity)

```
 class MediaModule extends ContentModule
 {

  private $type = 'mediaModule';

  #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: MediaElement::class, inversedBy: 'mediaModules', cascade:["persist"])]
  private $mediaElement;
```

### BasicpageType

```
class BasicpageType extends AbstractType
{
    $builder->add('contentModules', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => ContentModuleType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
        ]);
```

### ContentModuleType

```
class ContentModuleType extends AbstractType
{
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder) {
        $child = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        
        if ($child instanceof TextModule) {
            $form->add('text', TextareaType::class);
        }

        if ($child instanceof MediaModule) {
            $form->add('mediaElement', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'App\Entity\ContentModule\MediaModule\MediaElement',
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => 'Mediaelement: '));
        }
```

### And finally the rendering

```
      <div class="sub" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.contentModules.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"
           data-entitytype="contentModule"> 

            {% for module in form.contentModules %}
                {{ form_row(module) }}
            {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

the problem is that i can render a prototype of a contentModule, but cant get any prototypes of the inherienced entities.